# Get value/attr of clicked button as event.data with .on("click"...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, button, attr

I need to get the value or any other attr of a clicked button to use it as `event.data` within a function.

Here is the setting:

- got 26 buttons with value/text from "A" to "Z" as control for a list by alphabet.
- each button has same class="byalpha"
- each button starts the same ajax-search-function which gets json-data from sql to make a list
- by clicking a button of class="byname" the unique value (e.g. "B") should be delivered as event.data.letter to the function

I could get that working with other controls of the function using radio-inputs and stuff:

```
$( "input[name=selectdept]" ).on ("click", {  searchdept: function (){ return $( "input[name=selectdept]:checked" ).val()}}, startsearch );
```

So as you see, clicking the input fires the `function(startsearch)` and gets the value of the input as `event.data.searchdept` to be used inside the function. Everything working fine.

But trying that with the buttons is driving me crazy. I tried everything I could only imagine. Since I have to get the button by class and not by unique name or id I can't use way like with the radio-input. I tried to get any attr by using `$(this)`. But just comes up with "undefined". Some of my approaches:

```
$(".byname").on ("click", {letter: $(this).attr('value')}, searchdept );
```

or

```
$(".byname").on ("click", {letter: function(){ return $(this).attr("value")}}, searchdept );
```

or any type of

```
.val()  // .attr() // .text() // .html()  .... you name it
```

Somewhere here I found that **"event.target.value"** that would deliver the right value (e.g. "B" for button B) but is not a good solution in the context of my function, since there are in total 3 different ways (26 Buttons / 4 radio-inputs / text-input ) to start the function and the delivered values would make it complicated.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code? even if you can fiddle it then it would be great.

Comment: will you be able to change the click handler... can you share the click handler

Comment: by the the way the `this` that you are accessing is not the event target object it is the `letter` function which is also an object and does not have the methods that you are trying to access, btw why are you trying to pass the value to the event object, can't you just call the method within the onclick callback.

Comment: `<input type="button" />` or `<button></button>` elements ? Can include `html` at original post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I could not really understand what you were trying to do here, but guessed that you wanted to get the value of the data variable which you have set for each button.

I recreated your scenario 
**EDIT** - Updated the Javascript code and now it seems to be working as per your requirements

### HTML

```js
$('.byalpha').on('click', {
    'letter': function(element) {
      return $(element).data('letter');
    }
  },

  function(e) {
    $('#picked_letter').html(e.data.letter(this));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="byalpha" type='button' value='A' data-letter="a" />
<input class="byalpha" type='button' value='B' data-letter="b" />
<input class="byalpha" type='button' value='C' data-letter="c" />
<input class="byalpha" type='button' value='D' data-letter="d" />
<input class="byalpha" type='button' value='E' data-letter="e" />

<hr/>
<div>
  <span>Letter : </span>  <span id="picked_letter"></span>
</div>
<hr/>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.byalpha').on('click', 
    {'letter': function (element) {
            return $(element).data('letter');
        }
    }, 
    function (e) {
        $('#picked_letter').html(e.data.letter(this));
    }
);
```

here is a link for the working sample

http://jsfiddle.net/70fje1mh/2/

Comment: That's it!!! You're the man!

So basically i was quite close with the part of getting the data from the element. `$( ".byname" ).on ("click", {letter: function (element) {return $(element).data('letter')}}, searchdept);`

the second part of your example (function (e)) is not needed in my setting. 
BUT the the deciding factor actually was the **(this)** in recalling the eventdata --> `event.data.letter(this)` for the function "searchdept"

THX*1001!

Comment: Yeah since you passed the method that would get executed, I just wanted to capture the callback, thats why  ?